# Button won't bring me to next URL after validating 3 input fields

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I am trying to get all 3 inputs from the users and the button will bring them to the next page when clicked. I have already create a `if-else` statement for checking the 3 input fields and it works. But when I clicked on the button, it doesn't bring me to the next or URL.

```
function calcBody() 
{
    var b=document.forms["input"]["bust"].value;
    var w=document.forms["input"]["waist"].value;
    var h=document.forms["input"]["hips"].value;

    if (b == null || b == "", w == null || w == "", h == null || h == "")
    {
        alert("Please Fill All Required Field");
    }
    else
    {
        window.location = "http://www.google.com";
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you also put onclick="calcBody()" on your input button?

Comment: @vusan Yes. <input id="bigbutton" type="submit" value="Go to recommendation" onClick="calcBody()"/>

Comment: Change your input type from submit to button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prevent your form from submitting like:

```
<input id="bigbutton" type="submit" value="Go to recommendation" onClick="return calcBody()"/>
```

and in your script

```
function calcBody() 
{
    var b=document.forms["input"]["bust"].value;
    var w=document.forms["input"]["waist"].value;
    var h=document.forms["input"]["hips"].value;

    if (b == null || b == "", w == null || w == "", h == null || h == "")
    {
        alert("Please Fill All Required Field");
    }
    else
    {
        window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
    }
    return false
}
```

OR

change your input type submit to button

```
<input id="bigbutton" type="button" value="Go to recommendation" onClick="return calcBody()"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `window.location.href = "http://www.google.com"` and make sure that the element being clicked does not have it's own default action that causes odd behavior.

```
function calcBody() 
{
    var b=document.forms["input"]["bust"].value;
    var w=document.forms["input"]["waist"].value;
    var h=document.forms["input"]["hips"].value;

    if (b == null || b == "", w == null || w == "", h == null || h == "")
    {
        alert("Please Fill All Required Field");
    }
    else
    {
        window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't post an `HTML` therefor here's a working example that I just tested :

```
<form name="input" action="#" method="post">
    bust: <input type="text" name="bust"><br/>
    waist: <input type="text" name="waist"><br/>
    hips: <input type="text" name="hips">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="calcBody();return false;">
</form>
```

And the `JavaScript`

```
function calcBody() 
{
    var b=document.forms["input"]["bust"].value;
    var w=document.forms["input"]["waist"].value;
    var h=document.forms["input"]["hips"].value;

    if (b == null || b == "" || w == null || w == "" || h == null || h == "")
    {
        alert("Please Fill All Required Field");
    }
    else
    {
        window.location = "http://www.google.com";
    }
}
```

This code works, but actually if you want to redirect from the browser just don't use `form`, put all three `<inputs>` in a div and add a `<button>` to handle them/